# Recursivly change object nested property name

Tags: javascript

I have object with nested fields than named subItem I need to change names of this field to children.

How can this functionality be neatly implemented, perhaps there are ways besides recursion?

```
let data = [
  {
    name: 'Alex',
    subItem: [
      {
        name: 'Den',
        subItem: [
          
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

function transformData = (data) => {
  return data.map(stat=>{
    
  })
}

console.log(transformData(data))
```

//shoud be

```
let data = [
  {
    name: 'Alex',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Den',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can there be more levels of nesting or only this much?

Comment: more than 1 levels

Comment: So it is dynamic? which means there can be a lot of levels?

Comment: yes, many levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript already includes a recursive object transformer, `JSON. stringify` with `replacer` function:

```js
let data = [
  {
    name: 'Alex',
    subItem: [
      {
        name: 'Den',
        subItem: [ {name: 'Foo', subItem: []} ],
      }
    ]
  }
]



JSON.stringify(data, function(_, v) {
    if (v.subItem) {
        v.children = v.subItem
        delete v.subItem
    }
    return v
})

console.log(data)
```

In the simple case like this, you can also just manipulate the JSON string directly:

```
newData = JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(data)
        .replaceAll(`"subItem":`, `"children":`))
```

Comment: It looks good, but what if the object contains text with the title subItem: (

Comment: @Ksenia: `"subItem":` can only match a key in JSON, not a value or a part thereof.